# Setting TimeZone in DatePicker (Android)

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using DatePicker in my Android Application to display available dates that the user can pick. I want to display the dates in the GMT Time Zone so that all users see the same dates. I haven't found any way of modifying the TimeZone of the DatePicker. I saw that DatePicker picks the TimeZone by using the default TimeZone. So I changed the default TimeZone to GMT and it worked but now the overall TimeZone has changed so not the best solution. Anyone have any ideas on something better? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify setMinDate and setMaxDate with a long primitive. There is no way to include a specific timezone during the assignment. The method will always use the devices locale settings. [It's in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long)).

You have to first create the min and max dates you want to use then adjust for the local timezone of your device and then use their respective long's, (getTimeInMillis()), and assign it to min/max date properties of the DatePicker.

Comment: It is not it appears to be uing UTC 0 always, so when you select a date the timestamp will be off by 1 day if you're in the Americas.

Comment: I think it tries to be atemporal instead, but uses UTC timestamps to be compatible with default classes. However dates should be managed as timezoneless values once obtained, and also when set as initial value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void GetDate(final String flag) {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Canberra"));// here is your code

    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    userentered_Date = dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year;
                    Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth).getTime();
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
                    String strDate = df.format(date);
                    String e = sdf.format(date);


                    GetTime(strDate, e, flag);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);


    datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

This should get you working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code i used in my project for adjusting time to use it.

```
time_tab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Calendar c = getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(MINUTE);
            mYear = c.get(YEAR);
            mMonth = "" + (c.get    (MONTH) + 1);
            mDate = c.get(DATE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog tpd = new 
                                TimePickerDialog(NotificationActivity.this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int 
                                                  hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            Hour = hourOfDay;
                            Minute = minute;

                            int r = minute / 10;
                            if (r == 0) {
                                new_minute = "0" + minute;
                            } else {
                                new_minute = minute + "";
                            }
                            if (Hour > 12) {
                                new_hour = (hourOfDay - 12);

              notification_time.setText(newStringBuilder().append(new_hour)
                                        .append(":").append(new_minute));
                                notification_am_pm.setText("PM");
                            } else if (Hour == 12) {

                                new_hour = hourOfDay;
                                notification_time.setText(new 
                               StringBuilder().append(new_hour)
                                        .append(":").append(new_minute));
                                notification_am_pm.setText("PM");
                            } else {
                                new_hour = hourOfDay;
                                notification_time.setText(new StringBuilder().append(new_hour)
                                        .append(":").append(new_minute));
                                notification_am_pm.setText("AM");
                            }


                            int timestamp;
                            long time = 0;
                            try {

        SimpleDateFormat df = newSimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
       String dateStr = mDate + "-" + mMonth + "-" + mYear + " " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute;

                   df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                   Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
                   time = date.getTime();
                   timestamp = (int) time;
                   String newtimeStamp = "" + timestamp;
        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            tpd.show();
  }
```